# git checkout to origin after rebase

Tags: git, version-control, rebase

Here is the situation: I have an old branch `branch1` from `master` and I wanted to update it so I rebased `branch1` on `master` and that took me an hour of fixing conflict.
I still didn't force push the branch after rebasing but now I need to go bach to the `branch1` before rebasing without losing the rebasing effort that i did ( like doing reset `--hard origin/branch1`).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the reflog?

Comment: thank you, that actually solved the problem. I did reset hard to the origin then reset hard back to the last commit i did after rebasing.

Answer (score 1):

The theoretical answer is `git rerere` should deal with it.

[From the doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere)

> In a workflow employing relatively long lived topic branches, the developer sometimes needs to resolve the same conflicts over and over again until the topic branches are done (either merged to the "release" branch, or sent out and accepted upstream).
>
> This command assists the developer in this process by recording conflicted automerge results and corresponding hand resolve results on the initial manual merge, and applying previously recorded hand resolutions to their corresponding automerge results.

To avoid bad surprise, I recommend create a new branch.

```
git checkout -b branch1rebased
```

Go back to branch1

```
git checkout branch1
git reset --hard origin/branch1
```

fix and try the rebase.

Everything go well not need to do something else.
Nightmare of conflict abort rebase and go back to the previous branch

```
git rebase --abort
git checkout branch1rebased
```

Cherry pick your fix

```
git cherry-pick branch1
```

Fix if need the conflict